# Making assertions with mocha and chai when using react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, react-testing-library, jest-dom

I would like to add React Testing Library to a project that uses mocha and chai for unit tests. I am a bit stumped when it comes to writing assertions, most examples make use of jest and jest-dom. I am really keen to use assertions like `toBeInTheDocument` or `toHaveTextContent`

I am wondering if there is a chai plugin that is a suitable replacement for jest-dom?
or what alternative solutions you have found for using React Testing Library with mocha and chai?

Answer (score 4):

[chai-dom](https://github.com/nathanboktae/chai-dom) is an alternative. It's a plugin that provides a subset of assertions on the dom. Unfortunately, the assertions are not as declarative or extensive as jest-dom.

Using chai-dom, we'd use [`exist`](https://github.com/nathanboktae/chai-dom#exist) in place of `toBeInTheDocument` and [`text`](https://github.com/nathanboktae/chai-dom#texttext) in place of `toHaveTextContent`.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend matchers in your test configuration file to use Jest's ones or any others.

1. Install the @testing-library/jest-dom which contains the matchers
2. Be sure you are indicating a configuration file for mocha, this is one of the ways to do it through .mocharc.js

   ```
   // .mocharc.js

   module.exports = {  
     ...  
     require: ['test.config.js']  
   };
   ```
3. Now in add this into your **test.config.js** file, not **runtime config** which is for different purposes.

   ```
   // test.config.js

   // Imports Jest's matchers  
   const extendExpectMatchers = require('@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers');  
   // Imports expects  
   const expect = require('expect');  
   // Extend expects with @testing-library/jest-dom  
   expect.extend(extendExpectMatchers);
   ```

Then use it as usual in your tests

```
expect(screen.getByText('Whatever')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: bro he said he wants to use mocha not jest.  This is an example using jest matchers.

Comment: that's true, I miss read the question. But still, my answer helps more than yours :P